# How to access Windows Phone 8 contacts from desktop app

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, usb, backup

I need to access Windows Phone 8 contacts/pictures/sms messages from Windows desktop/store app by using c#, when phone is connected with usb cable. How can I do this ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: I need some general directions, is it possible, how to "attack" this problem, etc. I don't need exact solution or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access the contacts, SMS from the desktop. You have the ability to sync the content of the emulator with the Additional Tools that the emulator comes with. Read [this post](http://wpdevkvk.wordpress.com/2014/07/19/adding-your-own-photos-to-windows-phone-8-1-emulator/) it shows how to sync the content of the emulator to the hard disk of your desktop. Other than that, you have no access to the contacts, SMS from the desktop.

Comment: There is no API for that in .NET ?

Comment: To access that content from the Emulator, No there is not. you can only access them from an App running in the windows phone. But currently no access to SMS amoung other things.

Comment: if the answer is satisfactory please mark it as correct.